# Can I open website URL from Excel data file using Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium

I have an Excel file that contains all the URLs that I need to open

E.g:

```
1. example.com/archiveData.php?edit=testcase&id=29
2. example.com/archiveData.php?edit=testcase&id=30
3. example.com/archiveData.php?edit=testcase&id=31
4. example.com/archiveData.php?edit=testcase&id=32
5. example.com/archiveData.php?edit=testcase&id=33
6. example.com/archiveData.php?edit=testcase&id=34
...
```

(it's about 3000 URLs T_T)

I can not open it manually so Im thinking using Selenium IDE to do this
Since I'm very new in Selenium, so anyone could help me to answer my question...Can I open website URL from Excel data file using Selenium IDE?

Or please propose any free tools that I can do it easily

Many thanks!

Comment: What else do you need to do after opening the pages?
If you need screenshots AutoIt would do just fine, if you need to interact with it then you should learn selenium.

Comment: Yes this is possible to open url from Csv (not excel). What do you want to do after opening? Urls will be opened in same tab.

Comment: Thanks all, I want to open url then insert some data into that link, I also have a set of data that need to be inputted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot use `Selenium IDE` to solve your problem as it intended to simulate user actions in web-browser. But you can use programming language, for example, `Python` to read `Excel` file content (`xlrd` module) and to navigate to required `URLs` (`Selenium WebDriver` module) in same script.

Also, if you work with `Windows` OS you can try `AutoIT`/`AutoHotKey` automation tool for same purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I will use Selenium WebDriver

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by selenium RC or webdriver, with few lines of code. Try to go through basics of selenium.

Answer (score 0):

If you could convert the Excel file to a line delimited text file, then this could pretty easily be achieved by reading the file to an array, then manipulating the data based on the arrays value in a while loop.

Example:

**Links.txt**

```
www.google.com
www.facebook.com
www.youtube.com
www.tumblr.com
www.amarokstudios.com
```

**OpenLinks.au3**

```
#include <file.au3>

; Create an empty array to store the links later on in the script.
DIM $aArray

; Read you Links.txt file to an array, if there is an error, display an error message.

If _FileReadToArray(@ScriptDir & "\Links.txt", $aArray) then
Else
  MsgBox(0,"Error","An error occurred trying to read your file to an array!")
EndIf

; Now, all of the links should be stored in the array called "$aArray". The size of the array is stored in $aArray[0], the first link is in $aArray[1], second in $aArray[2], and so on.

; Now, we are going to declare the starting size of the array, so the loop knows how many times to run the code.

$i = $aArray[0]
; Next, we will declare the link to start on. Since the first link is stored in $aArray[1], we will set the value to 1.
$link = 1

; Now we will create a while loop that will run while the array size is larger than zero.

While $i > 0
; Open the Windows RUN box
Send("#r")
Sleep(250)
; Send the value of $aArray[$link]. Since we previously set $link equal to 1, it will send the value of $aArray[1], which as we said earlier, would contain the first link on our list.
Send($aArray[$link])
; Send the enter key
Send("{ENTER}")
; Sleep for 1 second to prevent code from overlapping itself
Sleep(1000)

#CS
    You can put code here to manipulate the data on each website. There are many different ways to do this. For example, if the location for each piece of data is the same, you could simple write one script here that will execute each time a new page loads.

    Another method is to create an if statement to check which website is currently loaded, then writing the logic For each page. Tedious, but well worth it if you are going to be doing this for the same pages.

#CE

; Add the value of 1 to the current link variable so the script can move on to the next link. For example, the first value of $aArray[$link] was equal to $aArray[1], but adding 1 to it would change $aArray[$link] to $aArray[2]

$link += 1

; Subtract 1 from the total array size so the loop knows how many more times to execute.
$i -= 1

; End the loop
WEnd
```

Here is the code without comments so you can see how it works.

```
#include <file.au3>

Dim $aArray
If _FileReadToArray(@ScriptDir & "\Links.txt",$aArray) then 
Else
   MsgBox(0,"Error","Error from Function")
EndIf

$i = $aArray[0]
$link = 1
while $i > 0
    Send("#r")
    Sleep(250)
    Send($aArray[$link])
    Send("{Enter}")
    Sleep(1000)

    ; Your code to manipulate data here
    $link += 1
    $i -= 1
WEnd
```

I know this doesn't answer your question specifically, but I hope it provides you with a reasonable alternative. With this method, you don't have to download any UDFs and it's a pretty short bit of code.

If you have any questions, feel free to let me know. I don't mind helping you figure this out until it works for you!